Can anti-Israel protesters be charged with obstruct movement to a public place
According to PC647c, "It is a crime to willfully and maliciously obstructs the free movement of any person on any street, sidewalk, or other public place"
It would seem on this viral video that anti-Israel protestors are blocking a UCLA student from entering the public university he attends. Do these actions qualify as PC647c violations?

These are provisions against sideshows. The protesters obstruct an entry, not a public road. There might be a different provision (or some generic catch-all provision), but likely not this specific one.

Do you know what the actual law enforcement and prosecution response has been? Here is one story that recounts the current and ongoing developments in this matter. https://abc7.com/classes-canceled-protest-at-ucla-pro-palestinian-encampment-violence/14750637/ and here noting 132 arrests with charging decisions pending. https://www.theguardian.com/us-news/article/2024/may/02/ucla-los-angeles-campus-violence-protests


Do these actions qualify as PC647c violations?

California Penal Code Section 647c states:

Every person who willfully and maliciously obstructs the free movement
of any person on any street, sidewalk, or other public place or on or
in any place open to the public is guilty of a misdemeanor.
Nothing in this section affects the power of a county or a city to
regulate conduct upon a street, sidewalk, or other public place or on
or in a place open to the public.

This is one of several possible charges in this situation, and while the link in the question is to one discussing its application to "sideshows" (i.e. blocking off a street for illegal street racing and similar conduct) the statute in question is not limited to a sideshow fact pattern.
There may be some question as to whether a walkway on a university campus is really a public place, since it is owned by the University of California (a California state government owned corporation) and isn't open to the general public.
But this statute is surely not the only charge available. If the public place issue prevents this offense from being charged, trespassing charges or failure to disperse charges, for example, might be available. And, in addition to state criminal charges, local Los Angeles ordinance violation charges might be available.
About 132 people have been arrested in the recent UCLA protests, according to the Guardian newspaper, and as of that time that report went to press, on May 2, 2024 at 3:21 p.m. EDT, a decision on what charges to bring against the people arrested had not been made by prosecutors.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
